# Does SQL injections only apply to webpages or will it also work on "normal" programs?

Tags: sql, sql-injection, barcode

My question what the header says, but I'm mainly interesting in knowing about injections via barcode scanners.

https://youtu.be/qT_gwl1drhc?t=22m36s

It seems dangerously easy to hide injections for the person who do the scanning.

Comment: They apply anywhere a user-supplied string can wind up un-sanitized e.g. in a query statement's `where` clause. I think the barcode standard being used would have to allow for alpha-numeric data, though.

Answer (score 4):

Barcode scanners will pass through any data they can decode (unless you've programmed them to ignore some families of barcodes) and in most cases, act as a keyboard device.  If you allow CODE128, this is a perfectly valid barcode:

[image: obligatory XKCD]

Regardless of what device they used to enter data, any input from the user needs to be validated first.

*for ref, see https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Barcodes are my favorite input that needs testing.  You do not want someone showing up at your conference and wrecking the entire registration system.  Works with QR Codes too.

Answer (score 1):

Any program which interacts with a database is potentially vulnerable to SQL injection, regardless of whether or not is a web page. The danger arises any time a user-entered string is put into SQL without being properly sanitized.

We just see it most often with web applications because almost all of those are backed back a database, and they are accessible by far more users.